# ruby get Time in given timezone

Tags: ruby, timezone

In ruby, how can I get current time in a given timezone? I know the offset from UTC, and want to get the current time in the timezone with that offset.

Comment: Please refer to the one I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577449/convert-time-to-other-timezone/44278155#44278155

Answer (score 54):

A simpler, more lightweight solution:

```
Time.now.getlocal('-08:00')
Time.now.getlocal(-28800)
```

Well documented [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-getlocal).

**Update 2021.12.23:** If you've got a [`tzdata` timezone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) like 'US/Pacific' instead of an offset and you're willing to pull in the `tzinfo` gem, you could also do this (with thanks to both @chadoh and @kevin [from below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702906/4417766)):

```
require 'tzinfo'

TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Pacific').now
```

Not really the problem as posed, but maybe helpful to folks in the future.

If you want to do this for moments other than `#now`, you should study up on the [Ruby Time class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html), particularly [`Time#gm`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-gm) and [`Time#local`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-c-local), and the [Ruby TZInfo classes](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo), particularly [`TZInfo::Timezone.get`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Timezone#get-class_method) and [`TZInfo::Timezone#period_for_local`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Timezone#period_for_local-instance_method)

Comment: Best, simplest answer. No require nor gems. Should be checked as solution. I was checking the docs how to grab a daylight shifting zone, btw. Like U.S. Pacific Time: sometimes '-08:00', sometimes '-07:00'.

Comment: This breaks when DST.

Comment: The original questioner asked about offsets and specified Ruby, not Rails. Offsets are much simpler than timezones precisely due to DST observance issues. This is why there's a separate timezone for Indiana, for example.

If you want to deal with timezones in Ruby, start by reading [this blog post](http://rpanachi.com/2016/07/04/ruby-is-time-to-talk-about-timezones#using-tzinfo) to understand how to deal with them. That said, here's a crappy one-liner to turn tz into offset including DST: `'%+.2d:00' % (TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Pacific').current_period.utc_total_offset / 3600)`

Comment: When I follow along with the code example here, I get that the offset for `'US/Pacific'` is `-1`. That's... not correct.

Comment: Did you `require 'tzinfo'` beforehand? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: chadoh's answer below is better. The problem here is that daylight saving time is not taken into account.

Comment: @JimMeyer That one-liner does not work, because offsets are not necessarily just integer hours, but can have minutes and seconds +5:30:30. Just pass `utc_total_offset` to `getlocal`

Comment: @AndreasProfous as I noted in an earlier comment, the original questioner stated they have the offset already, which would vary according to daylight savings. I didn't presume to tell them that they'd gotten the offset wrong. =]

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek True, there are definitely offsets that don't match *:00, which is why I labeled the example in my comment above as "crappy." Pull requests welcome. =]

Answer (score 17):

I'd use the [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) gem:

```
require 'active_support/time'
my_offset = 3600 * -8  # US Pacific

# find the zone with that offset
zone_name = ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys.find do |name|
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone[name].utc_offset == my_offset
end
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[zone_name]

time_locally = Time.now
time_in_zone = zone.at(time_locally)

p time_locally.rfc822   # => "Fri, 28 May 2010 09:51:10 -0400"
p time_in_zone.rfc822   # => "Fri, 28 May 2010 06:51:10 -0700"
```

Comment: when I installed the active_support gem, I needed to require 'active_support/time' in order to make your example work properly.

Answer (score 14):

For an UTC offset of x hours, the current time can be calculated with the help of ActiveSupport in Rails, as the others said:

```
utc_offset = -7
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[utc_offset].name
Time.zone = zone 
Time.zone.now
```

or instead of the two lines

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone(zone)
```

Or, if you do not have Rails, one can also use `new_offset` to convert a locate DateTime to another time zone

```
utc_offset = -7
local = DateTime.now
local.new_offset(Rational(utc_offset,24))
```

Comment: This should be considered the actual answer as it includes a purely ruby based solution.

Comment: Why didn't I find this earlier!?

`DateTime.now.in_time_zone(zone)`

So simple it's beautiful

Answer (score 8):

```
gem install tzinfo
```

Then

```
require 'tzinfo'

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Pacific')
Time.now.getlocal(tz.current_period.offset.utc_total_offset)
```

Comment: You can just call "tz.now" as well fyi.

Answer (score 5):

```
now = Time.now
now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') 
or 
now.in_time_zone('Asia/Manila')
```

Comment: `in_time_zone` requires ActiveSupport's `DateAndTime::Zones` extension.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to do it is to simply pass the offset (in integer form) to the ActiveSupport::TimeZone hash:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-8]
=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x7f6a955acf10 @name="Pacific Time (US & Canada)", @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: America/Los_Angeles>, @utc_offset=nil, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionInfo: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1320570000>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffsetInfo: -28800,0,PST>>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionInfo: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1331460000>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffsetInfo: -28800,3600,PDT>>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a `gem install active_support`, it installed activesupport-3.00, which gave me an error:

"You don't have tzinfo installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"

`tzinfo` is a gem that ActiveSupport uses -- it was a little cleaner for my purposes, doesn't have any external dependencies -- the downside is that it appears to leave everything looking like it is UTC, so if you want your timezones to look correct, `gem install activerecord` will install everything you need.  I'm including this answer mostly for reference for others that run into the same issue / googlability.

(use `gem install tzinfo`) to install the gem

```
require 'tzinfo'
zone = TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Eastern')
puts zone.now
```

there are a number of different ways to get the timezones, but you can see a list using

```
TZInfo::Timezone.all
```

Answer (score -4):

Just add or subtract the appropriate number of seconds:

```
>> utc = Time.utc(2009,5,28,10,1)           # given a utc time
=> Thu May 28 10:01:00 UTC 2009
>> bst_offset_in_mins = 60                  # and an offset to another timezone
=> 60
>> bst = t + (bst_offset_in_mins * 60)      # just add the offset in seconds
=> Thu May 28 11:01:00 UTC 2009             # to get the time in the new timezone
```

Comment: Note: You're still returning a UTC time, it just has been offset, which will cause all sorts of oddness if you try to compare times. A good test of this is whether or not the two are still equal.

Comment: Awesome, appears basically it's Time.now += number_of_seconds, thx!