# Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::TimeZone (NameError)

Tags: ruby, timezone

I have some lines of code in my Ruby script that gets the current date (mine is in GMT) and converts it to ET (Eastern Time).

I have this code in my Ruby script for that:

```
# get current time and date in ET
my_offset = 3600 * -5  # US Eastern

# find the zone with that offset
zone_name = ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys.find do |name|
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone[name].utc_offset == my_offset
end
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[zone_name]

time_locally = Time.now
time_in_zone = zone.at(time_locally)
```

The problem is it gives an error here (well, on this line): `zone_name = ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING.keys.find do |name|`: `uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::TimeZone (NameError)`

Anyone know what's wrong? I obtained this code segment from Stack Overflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927111/ruby-get-time-in-given-timezone).

Comment: Do you have require 'rubygems' and require 'active_support' at the top of that code? You need it if you don't.

Comment: Yeah, I have these require in my code. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
require 'active_support/time_with_zone'
```

After your other requires.

Comment: That solved that error, but now it gives a new error:

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:260:in at': undefined method in_time_zone' for Thu Dec 15 17:43:18 UTC 2011:Time (NoMethodError)
 from ruby ratings.rb:35`

Line 35 in my code is: `time_in_zone = zone.at(time_locally)`